# Multiple routers & access point setup

Tags: router

Could you please advise to proper router & secondary router setup for my staff building.  Our existing connection is as shown on the diagram.

However many of users are facing alternative disconnection, slowdown, IP conflict etc.

So please advise the best solution for routers IP config & WiFi setting.

[image: Hardware setup]

Comment: Hi,  The main router and EA 1900 routers are only my control.  All other routers are configured by my colleagues themselves; seems different ip address.

Comment: for example router EA 1900 is configured with 192.168.1.8 with DHCP turned off.  however dropping the connection.

Comment: All dhcp servers should be disabled, except that of the main router. Alternatively, choose different subnets for every router, but this means people in a subnet will be disconnected from all other subnets.

Comment: thank you sir. what about wifi settings for the secondary routers?  Do I need to follow the same channel, SSID etc. of Main Router configuration?

Comment: No, that's not my suggestion: I would use different SSIDs and, above all, **different channels**, as widely separated as possible, to decrease interference. Try, if possible, to have at any given point **at most** APs on channels 1,6,11, this will greatly mitigate (or possibly even outright solve) your problem with frequent disconnections.

Comment: If you are the IT Guy (or even just Nominated IT Guy) then your first duty is to tell people to stop abusing your network and take their shonky consumer routers home.  Give an ultimatum if you have to, tell them to loose them from the office or loose them permanently by way of an [EtherKiller](http://etherkiller.org/img/etherkiller.jpg) plugged into the port that their router is on.  Then replace all of their routers with **proper commercial hardware designed for the task**.  Networks built by people band-aiding bits of hardware together just means pain. Centrally managed hardware is good.

Answer (score 1):

This seems ... well a little terrifying, especially if all of these are consumer routers.

Lets start "Main router N type" Its a consumer router that's probably handling more connections than its designed for. I'd grab a spare pc with 2 NICs, and throw something like pfsense, or some other linux firewall distro on it. Some skill needed, but I'd either spare no effort or expense (pick one! Better yet, pick both!) here. If you have the budget, a proper gateway/firewall type thing would be a great idea.

Pick a ip address range. [RFC1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) covers that. Set aside a range for static addresses. Use DHCP everywhere and insist on it. I'd rather not go with a 192.168/16 range here, but only cause that feels amateur hour

You have *six* routers that may or may not be interfering with each other. No wait. 8 and a switch.

Lets start at the "top"

You want *everything* except the 'core' router acting as a pure AP. Instructions may vary between turning off DHCP, simply picking AP mode, and setting your router on fire and buying a decent AP. Proper enterprise APs would be a nice thing here, especially if they were the same brand/model and you could manage them together.

Next thing you need to do is a site survey. Once again, some proper enterprise APs would talk to each other and do a heatmap and other cool things. Grab a map of your building and a site survey tool for your phone/tablet/laptop (my preferred tool is no longer supported). Note down which APs you can see, signal strengths

You'd need to do a site survey to work out what exactly is going on. You'll want to make sure that you can see at least one AP at any location, any location where you can see 2 or 3 should have them on different channels - 1 6 and 11 should be the ones you use. Check connectivity around *fire doors* - I used to be in a school where the wifi would only cut out when a door was opened or closed.  Different SSIDs are reasonable for setting up initially, but a professional setup would have the same SSIDs, and devices would tend to switch. YMMV, but with *this* hardware different SSIDs would make error reporting easier

Review and <strike>adjust salt</strike> adjust your setup. Do site surveys again where there's issues, move gear if needed. Optimise it over a few months or so.

This is an overview - this is how I'd *build it* though clearly the details are at your disposal. I've not gotten much time with pfsense so I'm not really going to be able to go into depth there. If you need specific software support, work out your *exact* needs and ask at software recommendations stackexchange. For hardware, ask at hardware recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the connectivity between your main router and the other routers with static IPs.

Above that you have to be sure the other routers are not using the same subnet for there internal comunication 192.168.0.0/24.
One way to be sure of that is to change the subnet in the main router to 10.0.0.0/24 since 192.168.0.0 is very comonly used by many vendors ( that would solve the conflicts).